# Use dynamic programming to merge two arrays such that the number of repetitions of the same element is minimised

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, subsequences, bioinformatics

Let's say we have two arrays `m` and `n` containing the characters from the set `a, b, c , d, e`. Assume each character in the set has a cost associated with it, consider the costs to be `a=1, b=3, c=4, d=5, e=7`.

for example

```
m = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'a']
n = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'd']
```

Suppose we would like to merge `m` and `n` to form a larger array `s`.

An example of `s` array could be

```
s = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'd']
```

or

```
s = ['b', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'e']
```

If there are two or more identical characters adjacent to eachother a penalty is applied which is equal to: `number of adjacent characters of the same type * the cost for that character`. Consider the second example for `s` above which contains a sub-array `['d', 'd', 'd']`. In this case a penalty of `3*5` will be applied because the cost associated with `d` is `5` and the number of repetitions of `d` is `3`.

I need to design a dynamic programming algorithm which minimises the cost associated with `s`.

Does anyone have any resources, papers, or algorithms they could share to help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please edit the question to show an merged array that minimises the cost associated. This is a general rule: always include an example that shows the expected correct answer.

Comment: Does s = ['b', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'e'] minimises the cost?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an algorithm that computes the minimum cost that is about as simple as possible and as fast as possible.

1. Count the total number of each character in $m$ and $n$. Let them be $c(a), c(b), \cdots$ respectively. Let $x$ be one of $a,b,\cdots$ such that $c(x)$ is the maximum.
2. Let $\sigma$ be the sum of all $c(i)$ where $i$ goes through $a, b, \cdots$ except $x$.

   1. If $c(x)\le 1 + \sigma$, return 0.
   2. Else return $p(x)(c(x) -\sigma))$, where $p(x)$ is the penalty associated with $x$.

The time-complexity of the algorithm is $O(\ell)$, where $\ell$ is the sum of the length of $m$ and the length of $n$.

Since the algorithm above is simple and clear, there is no need to apply the heavy machinery of dynamic programming.

#### Exercises

Here are two exercises that prove the correctness of the algorithm above.

**Exercise 1.**  If $s(x)\le 1 + \sigma$, design a procedure to produce a merged array that does not have adjacent pairs of the same letter.

**Exercise 2.**  If $s(x)\gt 1 + \sigma$, then any merged array must have at least $s(x) -\sigma$ $x$s each of which is adjacent to another $x$. Design a procedure to produce a merged array that has no other penalties except for $s(x) -\sigma$ $x$s.

Comment: it also needs to produce s

Comment: @DanielPahor The statements in two exercises are hints for how to produce a merge array with the minimum penalty. Here is a further hint for exercise 2. Treat all characters other than $x$ as the same letter, say, $z$.

Comment: In fact I was thinking items coming from both lists have to respect initial order. It would have made DP relevant. But your answer is consistant with the question 2nd example... Now I just don't understand the need to have 2 lists.

Comment: @Vince I had thought the same as you before I posted my answer, as indicated by my comments to the question. DanielPahor, in case you had extra restrictions such as merging should be stable, i.e., the original array must be a subsequence of the merged array, please raise a new question. It would be great if you can add a reference to the problem or your motivation, bioinformatics.